# using logstash with elastic cloudid

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

There instructions on how to configure logstash with elastic cloud using the cloud.id are not complete.  Specifically the instructions do not say what to put into the output section in the *.conf file if you put the cloud.id and cloud.auth into logstash.yml. Using the cloud.id is supposed the negate the need to put the URL of the ES instance.

If you put nothing in the output section logstash throws a config error.  If you put something there, illogical since nothing should be needed, it tries to connect to ES on localhost:

```
 output {
      elasticsearch {
      }
    }
```

Here is error as logstash is not using the cloud.id.

```
[WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error. {:url=>"http://127.0.0.1:9200/", :error_type=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :error=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://127.0.0.1:9200/]
```

Comment: Seems using the cloud id not supported.  So you have to explicitly define the ES endpoint and send it the password.  Too bad for that.

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https://58571402f5464923883e7be42a037917.eu-central-1.aws.cloud.es.io:9243"]
    user => "elastic"
    password => "XXXXXXX"
    index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

You should repeat the login information in the output section despite it's being illogical, as stated [here](https://www.bmc.com/blogs/elasticsearch-logs-beats-logstash/). The output of your pipeline shall look something like this:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-central-1.aws.cloud.es.io:9243"]
    user => "myUsername"
    password => "myPassword"
 }
 stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`cloud.id` and `cloud.auth` are only meant for configuring:

- [internal modules](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logstash-modules.html) (such as netflow)
- the Logstash [monitoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/monitoring-logstash.html)
- the [centralized pipeline management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.1/logstash-centralized-pipeline-management.html)

The `elasticsearch` output is another beast that requires its own configuration and does not (yet) benefit from the main configuration.